# Payara docker with oracle db connection

Tags: oracle, payara

I have a java application running in payara docker which connects to oracle database with connection pool. A particular functionality button in ui when clicked calls a database stored procedure to  display some rows as result. When this functionality button is triggered multiple times in a single user sesion, it returns duplicate results. First time if it returns 2 rows( expected) , 2nd time would be 4 (2 extected results and 2 possibly from previous run) and then 6 and so on..i checked the database stored procedure which is running fine without duplication when directly run in db..Can you please help on this

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a flaw in UI or data layer. You can do the following:

- perform a Client SQLNET trace and check how many times the rows gut shipped.